# compiler un programme c++ sous bada sdk

Tags: sdk, bada

I installed BADA SDK and I tried to compile a "hello world" program but it doesn't work. Every time the problem is "Launch failed. Binary Not Found". I installed the C++ compiler under MinGW and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a typical problem of Eclipse users.
See [here](http://codingrecipes.com/eclipse-launch-failed-binary-not-found-and-netbeans) for the discussion on what you could do.
The first thing to try is to BUILD your application. There should be a button.

PS: I hope you can read english.

Answer (score 0):

(moved from comment to answer)
is your current directory in your PATH?  This is OS dependent, but should be something like export PATH=$PATH:.  (Note that I still like my answer, even after the translation)